# Consulta sobre Variables JS y .val

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando mostrar por consola la variable ya declarada, que toma el value de un input.

El tema es que estas variables que tiene el modal se van llenando y al presionar agregar_funcionar este me arroja datos vacios, pero al recargar el sitio me trae los datos correctos que tiene el formulario.

Agregué un console.log directo a lo que llena la variable, y al verlo por consola me trajo la info correcta, los siguientes siguen apareciendo en blanco.

```
function agregarFuncionarioResponsable(){

$('#modal-agregra-funcionario').fadeIn();

rut = $("#rut_funcionario").val();
dv = $("#dv_funcionario").val();
nombre = $("#nombres_funcionario").val();
apellido_pat = $("#apellido_pat_funcionario").val();
apellido_mat = $("#apellido_mat_funcionario").val();
emailA = $("#email-a").val();
emailB = $("#email-b").val();
cargo = $("#cargo_funcionario").val();


$("body").on("click","#agregar-funcionario",function(){
    console.log( $("#rut_funcionario").val());
    console.log(dv);
    console.log(nombre);
    console.log(apellido_pat);
    console.log(apellido_mat);
    console.log(emailA);
    console.log(cargo);
```

Lo ideal es que una vez que me confirme que está declarada la variable con la info que necesito este se guarda en la bd

```
$.post("../../controllers/asignar-funcionario.php",{
        rut_funcionario         :rut,
        dv_funcionario          :dv,
        nombres_funcionario     :nombre,
        apellido_pat_funcionario:apellido_pat,
        apellido_mat_funcionario:apellido_mat,
        email_funcionario       :emailA,
        cargo_funcionario       :cargo
    },function(res){
        res = res.trim();
        console.log(res);
        if (res == "ok") {
```

Alguna ideal del por qué del problema?

Saludos

Comment: Tu código está incompleto, no hay llaves para ver dónde terminan las funciones y tampoco especificas si primero defines las variables en contexto global para luego acceder dentro de las funciones. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar más información.

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien la pregunta, el usuario rellena los datos, por lo tanto estás tratando de obtenerlos antes de tiempo.
Al hacer `rut = $("#rut_funcionario").val();` ni bien se muestra el modal, estás tratando de tomar el valor de ese input en ese mismo momento (y eso es antes que el usuario ingrese la información).

Para obtener la información que ingresó el usuario, debes tomarla en el momento que el usuario hace clic en el botón `agregar-funcionario`. Es por eso que el `console.log( $("#rut_funcionario").val());` sí te funciona y el resto no.

En concreto, deberías mover tus asignaciones hasta adentro de la función de clic. algo así:

```
function agregarFuncionarioResponsable(){

    $('#modal-agregra-funcionario').fadeIn();
    
    $("body").on("click","#agregar-funcionario",function(){
        rut = $("#rut_funcionario").val();
        dv = $("#dv_funcionario").val();
        nombre = $("#nombres_funcionario").val();
        apellido_pat = $("#apellido_pat_funcionario").val();
        apellido_mat = $("#apellido_mat_funcionario").val();
        emailA = $("#email-a").val();
        emailB = $("#email-b").val();
        cargo = $("#cargo_funcionario").val();

        console.log(rut);
        console.log(dv);
        console.log(nombre);
        console.log(apellido_pat);
        console.log(apellido_mat);
        console.log(emailA);
        console.log(cargo);
        
        //y también por aquí ya podrías enviar los datos usando $.post
    }
}
```

Comment: Eso hice y funcionó muy bien.

Comment: Me alegro. Considera [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) :)

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en que declaraba fuera de la acción del onclick.

Ya resolví el problema.

Gracias a todos